# PdhAddCounterW() failed: unknown error when starting a demo

Tags: openvino

I followed instructions on https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/omz_demos.html#doxid-omz-demos.

I finished the setup/installation, downloaded the needed models with the omz_download tool and tried to start the interactive demo:

`interactive_face_detection_demo ^ --loop ^ -m "C:\Intel\face-detection-adas-0001\FP16\face-detection-adas-0001.xml"`

```
[ INFO ] version: 2022.1.0
[ INFO ] build: 2022.1.0-7019-cdb9bec7210-releases/2022/1
[ INFO ] Reading model: C:\Intel\face-detection-adas-0001\FP16\face-detection-adas-0001.xml
[ INFO ] Model name: mobilenet_ssd_672x384
[ INFO ] Inputs:
[ INFO ] data, f32, {1,3,384,672}, [N,C,H,W]
[ INFO ] Outputs:
[ INFO ] detection_out, f32, {1,1,200,7}, [...]
[ INFO ] The model C:\Intel\face-detection-adas-0001\FP16\face-detection-adas-0001.xml is loaded to CPU
[ INFO ] Device: CPU
[ INFO ] Number of streams: 1
[ INFO ] Number of threads: AUTO
[ ERROR ] PdhAddCounterW() failed: unknown error
```

**How can I get more information about that error / is this a problem with my setup?
(I was able to get everything running on another machine)**

```
System information:
Systemmodell Surface Pro 4
Betriebsystemname Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.19043 Build 19043
Prozessor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2496 MHz, 2 Kern(e), 4 logische(r) Prozessor(en)
RAM: 4GB
openvino_2022.1.0.643
4.5.5-90-gc3d60a6ca (OpenVINO/2022.1)
Visual Studio 16 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error appears to be related to Windows performance-counter-API and this error is not related to OpenVINO. For more information about PdhAddCounterW(), you can refer to [PdhAddCounterW function (pdh.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pdh/nf-pdh-pdhaddcounterw).

On another note, try specifying input to the demo as it requires an input to process. Here is an example command:

```
interactive_face_detection_demo -m "C:\Intel\face-detection-adas-0001\FP16\face-detection-adas-0001.xml" -i  <path_to_video>\<input_video>.mp4
```